# FBX Animation Export Problem

Tags: animation, export, .fbx

I have a problem when exporting animation in FBX to other softwares. Even if I import the FBX file back to Blender the animation goes wrong.
(I baked all actions by the way). File is below:
http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=49510